# Select-AzureRmSubscription shows enter valid subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, windows-10, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Hi i have this script to login-list the subscriptions-select subscription and select the resource group and continue with my script.

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Login with your Azure Account"
Add-AzureRmAccount
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "Your Available Subscriptions"
Get-AzureRmSubscription | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$subscriptions = @(Get-AzureRmSubscription | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)
$flag = $true
while ($flag) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter target Subscription name :' -NoNewline
    $subscriptionName = Read-Host
    foreach ($temp in $subscriptions) {
        if ($temp -eq $subscriptionName) {
            Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
            $flag = $false
            break
        }
    }
    if ($flag -eq $true) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Enter valid Subscription name"
    }
}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White "Selected Subscription is : " -NoNewline
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $subscriptionName
Write-Host -ForegroundColor White 'Your Available Resource Groups'
Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName
$resourceGroups = @(Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ResourceGroupName)
$flag = $true
while ($flag) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green 'Enter target Resource group name :' -NoNewline
    $resourceGroupName = Read-Host
    foreach ($temp in $resourceGroups) {
        if ($temp -eq $resourceGroupName) {
            Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Tag @{}
            $flag = $false
            break
        }
    }
    if ($flag -eq $true) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Enter valid Resource group name"
    }
}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow "Selected Resource group is : "$resourceGroupName
```

When i run the above script in windows 8 machine it works fine and i am able to select the MPN Subscription. But when i run the same script in windows 10 machine , it throws error stating **Please provide a valid tenant or valid subscription**

Attached image for reference - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YlfF.jpg

Comment: Could you show me the output of this command `Get-AzureRmSubscription`?

Comment: update azure powershell to latest version

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fec4E

Comment: @4c74356b41 actually in the windows 10 machine it is 5.1.16299.98 and in the 8.1 machine it is 5.1.14409.1012

Comment: @HariHaran could you please try to use ID?

Comment: Ya trying wait a sec

Comment: Id works fine , but why can't i use the name ? its working on one machine and not on another. any idea ?

Comment: @HariHaran Could you please try to use this command to select subscription?

`Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 'Visual Studio Enterprise - MPN'`

Comment: Thank you , i made my mind and switched from obtaining name to Id and it works fine now